# How can we pass shipping address in paypal recurring payment?

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring

I am using direct payment for recurring in Paypal.
How can we pass shipping address?

Comment: Show the code you have tried and we will help you :)

Comment: Kindly refer to this https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/paypal-sample-code/how-pass-shipping-address-alongside-cart-paypal

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the address to the shipto address fields:

```
SHIPTONAME     
SHIPTOSTREET
SHIPTOSTREET2
SHIPTOCITY
SHIPTOSTATE
SHIPTOZIP
SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE
SHIPTOPHONENUM
```

for example as the following:

```
SHIPTONAME=mr+alexSHIPTOSTREET=berlin+street&SHIPTOSTREET2=highway+no+43&SHIPTOCITY=newyork&SHIPTOSTATE=AL&SHIPTOZIP=12603&SHIPTOCOUNTRY=US&SHIPTOPHONENUM=1111111111
```

you can have a look at: 
 [Payments Pro - Direct Payments - Recurring Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/website-payments-pro/payments-pro-direct-payments-recurring-payments) 
[Payments Pro - Direct Payments - Recurring Payments - IPN](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/website-payments-pro/payments-pro-direct-payments-recurring-payments-ipn)

Comment: Thanks, I would like to implement it.